# php convert two different date formats into single date format

Tags: php, date

How would I change Following strings into specific customized format using php.

CHANGE
11/16/2012
11-16-2012

To
2012-16-11

Comment: Do you *really* want to have the year value twice and lose the month value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking how to get `Year-Month-Year`, or how to handle either hyphens or slashes, so the `funkyDateString` function  does both:

```
function funkyDateString($date) {
    return date("Y-m-Y", strtotime(preg_replace('#-#', '/', $date)));
}

echo funkyDateString("11/16/2012");
echo funkyDateString("11-16-2012");
```

If you need the date formatted differently, then look up the formatting options in php's [date docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use class [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) to make it easier working with dates.

Here's sample code for your input/output:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('11/16/2012');
echo $date->format('Y-d-Y');
```

**Edit:** you can use following regex pattern `\d+/\d+/\d+` to extract date from long string.

Comment: The next question will be how to extract the date string from the long one

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldDate = '11/16/2012';
$newDate = date('Y-d-m',strtotime($date1));
```

Use combinations here to get exact output format:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtodate(11-16-2012);
$ans = date('Y-d-Y',$date);
echo $ans;
```

Comment: strtodate() convert the date in unix timestamp.
and than you can convert it in any format you want.